# endpoint not found when multiple parameters passing wcf rest service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, wcf-endpoint

This is my OperationContract for Single Parameter

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "xml/{id}")]
    XmlElement GetXmlData(string id);
```

http://localhost/rest/xml/1

It is working fine.

And then i would like to add one more parameter . . .

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "xml/{id}/{name}")]
    XmlElement GetXmlData(string id, string name);
```

http://localhost/rest/xml/1/smith

It is return "Endpoint Not Found"

How can i solve this issue? Please help. Thanks you.

This is my web.config file for System.serviceModel

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>      
  <service behaviorConfiguration="RESTFulWCFService.PersonServiceBehavior" name="RESTFulWCFService.PersonService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RESTFulWCFService.IPersonService" behaviorConfiguration="web">          
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>        
    <behavior name="RESTFulWCFService.PersonServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Did you try this UriTemplate = "xml?{id}&{name}"

Comment: yes, i tried now but it is not working also . . . thanks.

Comment: Try this one also UriTemplate = "xml/?id={id}&name={name}" and call the URL like this [your rest service URL]/xml/?id=2&name=xyz

Comment: thanks, this one also not working . . .

Comment: are you sure? can you show the updated code? this one should work

Comment: one more thing..also check ifservice is running by calling http://localhost/rest

Comment: yes, it is sure. . . it not working . . . thanks.

Comment: yes service is running by calling localhost/rest. Because of one parameter is working (http://localhost/rest/xml/1). I only have problem when i pass to multiple parameter. thanks.

Comment: can you show me the updated code? also how are you calling the service ? The approach I mentioned should work....may be you overlook something

Comment: the updated code was simple, just copy your code( UriTemplate = "xml/?id={id}&name={name}") and updated it. The calling this service is just browse from Browser(ie and chrome).

Comment: how you call the service is also important here.....This should wok if you call the service like this http://localhost/rest/xml/?id=1&name=smith....Anyway, without the seeing the URL and I cannot comment what is going on wrong here...

Comment: i tried to call like this but it is still not working for me. anyway thanks for your time and help,